# How can i generate both dashboard and graphics generator in the same command?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way to get both the dashboard and graphics generator using the same non-GUI command in JMeter?

I am generating the dashboard using the below command.

a) `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl`
b) `jmeter -g result.jtl -o /report/destination/folder`

I am generating the graphics generator using the below command.

`sh jmeter -n -t /source/TestCSV.jmx -l /resultsfolder/Results.csv`

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Generating Reports](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)  chapter you should change your command to something like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /report/destination/folder
```

Other option is combining your 2 commands into one using `&&` operator (it will still be 2 separate commands)

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl && jmeter -g result.jtl -o /report/destination/folder
```

References:

- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)